# Most of my hard drive is inaccessible, full storage, cannot install anything. /dev/sda2 825G 7.8G 775G 1% /

Tags: mount

when trying to update my machine or install anything, I get an error of no space left.

```
alex@servercomputer:~$ sudo apt install lvm2
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I checked my storage, and all of my 5 gigabytes were allocated mostly to `/var/lib/snapd/snaps` to a bunch of old snaps, preventing my machine from working, causing timeout errors when trying to remove old snaps. But I have a 1TB harddrive...

after running df-h I noticed something strange:

```
alex@servercomputer:~$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           784M   79M  706M  10% /run
/dev/sda2       825G  7.8G  775G   1% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        21G  6.6G   13G  34% /home
/dev/sda4       5.6G  5.6G     0 100% /var
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1891
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2751
/dev/loop7      461M  461M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/102
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop6      350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
/dev/loop8       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop9       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1434
/dev/loop3      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop5      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop10      82M   82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop14      74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/634
/dev/loop13      74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/750
/dev/loop18     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop17      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop11     249M  249M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
/dev/loop20      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop12     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop16     120M  120M     0 100% /snap/mc-installer/588
/dev/loop19      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19361
/dev/loop15     106M  106M     0 100% /snap/mc-installer/613
/dev/sda1       945M  294M  587M  34% /boot
/dev/sda7       976M  5.3M  970M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           784M   68K  784M   1% /run/user/1000
```

[Screenshot of df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCDFy.png)

I am new to linnux (obviously) but this is very confusing. My / directory (which I can cd to from where I was) is taking up almost my entire hard drive even though I do not have access to it. It appears that my entire system is working on the /dev/sda4 directory which has been used up completely and I cannot install anything to fix this problem.

sorry for strange format this is my first time posting here
Anything helps! Thank you

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Is is used as a desktop/laptop or a server? Is this Ubuntu in the cloud? Add these information in your question. Please format pasted text from the terminal as `code` using the {_} icon of the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. This is a question answer site, but I don't see a question. You know snaps are eating up your 5GB `/var` partition. Why do you have a separate partition for `/var` if you are new to Linux. Why not the default installation? What do you wan to do? Increase the `/var/ partition? Delete old snaps? What happens when you try?

Comment: Your `/var` is on a separate partition and that is full ... Moving `/var` to `/dev/sda2` under `/` would solve it and after that, **carefully**, you can delete `/dev/sda4` and utilize the un-allocated space to expand `/dev/sda3` i.e. `/home` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a larger `/var` partition. It is used for things including the cache used to download and hold `.deb` packages installed/downloaded by APT and such.

Expand your `/var` partition and expect that it will need to have free space in the future.